# Bootstrap 3: center navbar and change floating

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

First of all I'm new to Bootstrap and fluid web-design. 
Here is the following situation I'm stuck with:

I can't seem to figure out how to:
1) dynamically center the navbar between the two big boxes so that the left and right margin are always the same and
2) to change the direction the navitems float when the window size decreases: I want the nav items not to float downwards when there isn't enough space to display them inline but for them to float upwards (the nav bar is fixed to the bottom as a sticky footer).

I'm really grateful for any help since this got me really frustrated.

Here is the code:

```
<body class="wallpaper1230x450px">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="bigbox"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/255x290/000/fff.jpg" alt="bigbox"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="navitem">
                            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x90/000/fff.jpg" alt="navitem">
                        </li>
                        <li class="navitem">
                            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x90/000/fff.jpg" alt="navitem">
                        </li>
                        <li class="navitem">
                            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x90/000/fff.jpg" alt="navitem">
                        </li>
                        <li class="navitem">
                            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x90/000/fff.jpg" alt="navitem">
                        </li>
                        <li class="navitem">
                            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x90/000/fff.jpg" alt="navitem">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="bigbox"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/255x290/000/fff.jpg" alt="bigbox"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: And any specific CSS?

Comment: I managed to solve the first problem, but the second one still gives me a headache. Is it even possible to change the direction of floating from downward to upwards???